# VC C++: lib file missing in release built

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2012

i have here a strange behaviour with VS2012.

I have a C++ dll project, with an export defnition file. In Debug built everything is fine, a dll and a lib file is generated.
In Release built only a dll file is generated.

Best
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the .def file is specified in the project's Propert Pages in **Configuration Properties | Linker | Input | Module Definition File** in both the Debug and Release configurations.